# SwiftUI slide transition

Tags: swiftui

```
struct Flashcard: View {
  @State var tangoID = randomNum
  @State var refreshToggle = false
  @State var showingSheet = false
  @State var bookmarked = tangoArray[randomNum].bookmark
  @State public var showingNoMoreCardsSheet = false


  @State private var showResults: Bool = false
  @State private var fullRotation: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    let zstack = ZStack {

      Frontside(id: $tangoID, sheet: $showingSheet, rotate: $fullRotation)
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.showResults ? 180.0 : 0.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.fullRotation ? 360.0 : 0.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
        .zIndex(self.showResults ? 0 : 1)


      Backside(id: $tangoID, sheet: $showingSheet, bookmark: $bookmarked, results: $showResults, rotate: $fullRotation)
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.showResults ? 0.0 : 180.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: -1.0, z: 0.0))
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.fullRotation ? 360.0 : 0.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
        .zIndex(self.showResults ? 1 : 0)

    }
    .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
      ActionSheet(title: Text("Finished 終わり"), message: Text("お疲れさま！ But feel free to keep going."), buttons: [.default(Text("はい"))]);
    }
    .onTapGesture {
      self.handleFlipViewTap()
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Study")
    .contextMenu(menuItems: {Button(action: {
      tangoArray[randomNum].bookmark.toggle()
      database.updateUserData(tango: tangoArray[randomNum])
      self.fullRotation.toggle()
    }, label: {
      VStack{
        Image(systemName: tangoArray[randomNum].bookmark ? "bookmark" : "bookmark.fill")
          .font(.title)
        Text(tangoArray[randomNum].bookmark ? "Remove bookmark" : "Bookmark")
      }
    })
    })

    return zstack
  }



  private func handleFlipViewTap() -> Void
  {
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25))
    {
      self.showResults.toggle()
    }
  }
}
    public struct Frontside: View  
    {  
      @Binding public var id: Int  

      public var body: some View  
      {  
        ZStack{  


          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)    
            .frame(width: 140, height: 149)  
            .zIndex(0)  

          VStack {  
            Text(tangoArray[self.id].kanji)  

            .font(.system(size: 24))  


            .fontWeight(.regular)  
            .padding(25)  
            .lineLimit(3)   
            .zIndex(1)  

            Spacer()  
          }  

          VStack {  
            Spacer()  
            HStack {  

              Button(action: {  
                incorrect(i: self.id)  
                checkAttempts()  
                self.id = nextCard()   
              }) {  
                Image(systemName: "xmark")  
                  .font(.headline)  
                  .opacity(0.4)  

              }  

              Button(action: {  
                correct(i: self.id)  
                checkAttempts()  
                self.id = nextCard()   
              }) {  
                Image(systemName: "circle")  
                  .font(.headline)  
                  .opacity(0.4)  

              }  

            }  
          }  
          .zIndex(2)  
        }  
      }  
    }  

I have a view which is a flashcard. When the user taps on the incorrect button I want the flash card to slide to the left of the screen, and when the user taps on the correct button I want the flash card to transition/slide to the right of the watch screen. How do I do that?
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the user taps on the incorrect button I want the flash card to
>   slide to the left of the screen, and when the user taps on the correct
>   button I want the flash card to transition/slide to the right of the
>   watch screen

I created a minimum viable example to show you a possible solution. Take a look and tell me if I can help you more.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let objWidth = CGFloat(100)
    private let objHeight = CGFloat(200)
    private let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width;
    private let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height;
    @State private var objOffset = CGFloat(50)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: objWidth, height: objHeight)
                .background(Color.black)
                .position(x: objOffset, y: (screenHeight-objHeight)/2.0)
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation{
                    self.move()
                }
            }) {
                Text("TAP")
            }
        }
    }

    private func move() {
        if objOffset > screenWidth/2.0 {
            objOffset = objWidth/2.0
        } else {
            objOffset = screenWidth-objWidth/2.0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see what you are doing there. However, I was hoping there was a quick solution using .transition and moving to the leading or trailing edge. I just can't figure out how to use those statements in my code.

Comment: @alamodey transition animations are not meant for what you need. They are meant to animate views when they are created and inserted in the view hierarchy or they are removed from the view hierarchy. If you have to just move a view you can’t use transition animations. You need the usual simple animations. If you can post your full code (so that I can copy/paste it) I’ll be happy to help you further.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have pasted more of my code. I have another issue which I have asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502709/swiftui-contextmenu-not-refreshing which relates to the context menu that I am using to save things to bookmarks. Would be great if you could advise on that as well. Thanks!