# SwiftUI contextMenu not refreshing

Tags: swiftui

```
      var body: some View {
        let zstack = ZStack {

          Frontside(id: $tangoID, sheet: $showingSheet, rotate: $fullRotation)
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.showResults ? 180.0 : 0.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.fullRotation ? 360.0 : 0.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
            .zIndex(self.showResults ? 0 : 1)


          Backside(id: $tangoID, sheet: $showingSheet, bookmark: $bookmarked, results: $showResults, rotate: $fullRotation)
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.showResults ? 0.0 : 180.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: -1.0, z: 0.0))
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.fullRotation ? 360.0 : 0.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
            .zIndex(self.showResults ? 1 : 0)

        }   
        .contextMenu(menuItems: {Button(action: {
          tangoArray[randomNum].bookmark.toggle()
          database.updateUserData(tango: tangoArray[randomNum])
        }, label: {
          VStack{
            Image(systemName: tangoArray[randomNum].bookmark ? "bookmark" : "bookmark.fill")
              .font(.title)
            Text(tangoArray[randomNum].bookmark ? "Remove bookmark" : "Bookmark")
          }
        })
        })
```

I'm trying to use a contextMenu to bookmark flashcard items. What I have found though is that even after randonNum has changed, so a different flashcard is presented, the bookmark in the context menu is still showing the previous card's status. For example, it's a filled bookmark if I just tagged the previous card as a bookmark.

Comment: Could you include more code for the whole view please?

Comment: Updated, I haven't included Frontside and Backside but if you want to see it maybe I should contact you privately instead of posting all my code here?